# How is compare different from compareTo in this Scala code?

Tags: compiler-construction, scala

I have a piece of code that I use to provide an implicit ordering for a priority queue:

```
type Time = Int
type Item = (Time, Whatever)

implicit def order(thisItem: Item): Ordered[Item] =
    new Ordered[Item] {
      override def compare(thatItem: Item) = {
        val result = thisItem._1 compareTo thatItem._1
        -result
      }
    }
```

Now this code doesn't compile on Scala 2.7 - the error message is:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : SimulationMode.this.Time
 required: ?{val compareTo: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method int2Integer in object Predef of type (Int)java.lang.Integer
 and method intWrapper in object Predef of type (Int)scala.runtime.RichInt
 are possible conversion functions from SimulationMode.this.Time to ?{val compareTo: ?}
        val result = thisItem._1 compareTo thatItem._1
                              ^
```

I found two ways to make it compile - either declare the type of ***result*** to be ***Int*** or change the use of ***compareTo*** to ***compare***. But my question is - is there a reason for such an error, what does the message mean and is this a bug in the scala compiler? compareTo just calls compare in the Ordered[A] trait and has the same signature... Plus both of them return Int, so why does it matter that I declare the type myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because an Int does not have a `compareTo` method just as the error says. Further when searching for an implicit that makes this work, the compiler found an ambiguity between a conversion to `java.lang.Integer` and `scala.runtime.RichInt` both of which provide a `compareTo` method. When you use `compare` instead of `compareTo` it works because only the `RichInt` conversion provides that method. FYI `compare` is from scala's `Ordered` trait.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say it works when you declare the type of result, that shouldn't make a difference, you'd have to post the code you're using that seems to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add to Rex's and Geoff's answers only one practical advice how to deal with ambiguities is to use type ascription:

```
val result = (thisItem._1: Integer) compareTo (thatItem._1: Integer)
```

Anyway, in this case using compare is probably the best solution as you are relying on Scala's types.

Answer (score 1):

The error arises from the different boxing of primitive integers in Scala and Java.  It's difficult for me to tell exactly what your code is doing--what type is `thisItem._1`?  Is it a primitive integer?

Anyway, the `compareTo` method is defined on both `java.lang.Integer` and `scala.runtime.RichInt` (Java and Scala's boxed integers, respectively).  compare is defined only on `scala.runtime.RichInt`.  So when you use compare, it is an unambiguous request; with `compareTo`, it doesn't know which boxing to use.